# Swiper slider, many slide in 1 page

Tags: javascript, slider, swiper.js

I call swiper slider and it work well when have 1 slide.
Create multiple Swiper with navigation divs
Init all with single call var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container');
Press navigation button Prev and Next on second button
They controls first and second Swiper simultaneously
what shoud i control nav button when have>1 slide
tks so much

Answer (score 0):

For each slider u need to create different containers with different class name, or Id, and use for this container own nav buttons for correct navigation